# combining tables role based access control and user information in sql

Tags: sql, relationship, rbac

I am looking to find a solution to structure information about users for a web based application and their personal information. users have certain capabilities or restrictions based on their role(role based access control) I am using MySQL and PHP.

I want to set up a database with the following tables:
User (ID, username, password, Role, Admin/employee/client/customer)
Roles(ID, role_name)

Roles can be: admin, employee, client, customer

Admin(ID, name, surname, more usefull information)
Employee(ID, name, surname, more usefull information)
client(ID, name, surname, more usefull information)
customer(ID, name, surname, more usefull information)

what I would like is to get all the information about a user, whether he is an admin, amployee, client or customer.

What would be an advisable method to do this in SQL.

Comment: What you are trying to do is reimplement from scratch an IAM/IAG solution. There are products out there (both commercial and open-source) that do just that. Look into things like Oracle Access Manager or WSO2 or ForgeRock. You will find what you need

Comment: Also, you should never ever ever implement your own table with usernames and passwords. That is just looking for trouble. How are your passwords secured? How is the table secured? How do you maintain password strength? You need an off-the-shelf authentication / user management solution not a home-grown one